# How to solve "ambiguous base class" error while deriving from recurring template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

The following code is failing to compile on both GCC 9.1 and Clang 9.0:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename ...> class Foo;

template<typename T>
class Foo<T>{
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo (1)\n";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ... Tail>
class Foo<T, Tail...> : public Foo<Tail...>  {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo (2)\n" ;
    }
};


class Bar : public Foo<std::string, int> {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    void test(Foo<Args...> f) {
        f.foo();
    }
};

class Baz : public Foo<int, std::string> {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    void test(Foo<Args...> f) {
        f.foo();
    }
};


int main() {
    Bar a;
    Bar b;
    a.test(b);

    Bar c;
    Baz d;
    c.test(d);   
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, it works fine with latest versions.

- [Godbolt GCC 9.1](https://godbolt.org/z/GrMcf6qsE) -> **NOK**
- [Godbolt Clang 9.0](https://godbolt.org/z/c1dd86e14) -> **NOK**
- [Godbolt GCC 12.1](https://godbolt.org/z/x1r1xKd97) -> **OK**
- [Godbolt Clang 12.0](https://godbolt.org/z/f5e1rM8W9) -> **OK**

Is this code actually valid? Why is it considered ambiguous? Is there any workaround that would work with previous versions of GCC and Clang?

Comment: This is [CWG2303](https://wg21.link/CWG2303)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible workaround for both GCC and Clang: an explicit `static_cast` to the base class. For convenience I inserted a type alias in the <s>derived</s> base* class, such that you can call `test` with the same syntax in both cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename ...> class Foo;

template<typename T>
class Foo<T>{
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo (1)\n";
    }
    using footype = Foo<T>;
};

template<typename T, typename ... Tail>
class Foo<T, Tail...> : public Foo<Tail...>  {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo (2)\n" ;
    }
    using footype = Foo<T, Tail...>;
};


class Bar : public Foo<std::string, int> {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    void test(Foo<Args...> f) {
        f.foo();
    }
};

class Baz : public Foo<int, std::string> {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    void test(Foo<Args...> f) {
        f.foo();
    }
};


int main() {
    Bar a;
    Bar b;
    a.test(static_cast<decltype(b)::footype>(b));

    Bar c;
    Baz d;
    c.test(static_cast<decltype(d)::footype>(d));   
    
    return 0;
}
```

Check it on goldbolt with [gcc 9.1](https://godbolt.org/z/43zGzMcMK) and [clang 9](https://godbolt.org/z/a3j37PMdr).

*Edit after comment.

Comment: Thanks. Any reason to put `baseclass` inside `Bar` and `Baz` instead of `Foo`? I feel it could be more generic, and avoid duplication of `<int, std::string>` template arguments if it's defined as `using baseclass = Foo<T, Tail...>;`, right?

Comment: ```decltype(b)::baseclass = Bar::baseclass``` would not work if defined inside ```Foo```. Indeed, you would like to cast to the base *template*-class, so that you do not deduce the template parameters of ```test```.

Comment: I'm thinking of something like that: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/a3j37PMdr). It compiles and seems to work fine. Am I missing something? It allows any number of classes to inherit from `Foo` without the required `using baseclass` workaround inside each of the subclasses.

Comment: I think yours is a better solution, I don't immediately see a drawback.

Comment: Alright, thanks! What do you think of updating your answer with this suggestion? I could accept it as the most complete one.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to relax a bit the requirements of the test() template function.

As in :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename ...> class Foo;

template<typename T>
class Foo<T>{
public:
    void foo() const {
        std::cout << "foo (1)\n";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ... Tail>
class Foo<T, Tail...> : public Foo<Tail...>  {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo (2)\n" ;
    }
};


class Bar : public Foo<std::string, int> {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void test(T&& f) {  // more relaxed requirements as temporary fix
        f.foo();        // until upgrade to newer compiler.
    }
};

class Baz : public Foo<int, std::string> {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void test(T&& f) {
        f.foo();
    }
};

class Buzz : public Foo<int>
{
    template<typename T>
    void test(T&& f) {
        f.foo();
    }
};


int main() {
    Bar a;
    Bar b;
    a.test(b);

    Bar c;
    Baz d;
    c.test(d);   

    Buzz e;
    c.test(e);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo (2)
foo (2)
foo (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Th code is valid and obviously not ambiguous enough to fail when compiling with the latest gcc compiler. You can use static_cast<> to be more explicit when using the older compiler.

As in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename ...> class Foo;

template<typename T>
class Foo<T>{
public:
    void foo() const {
        std::cout << "foo (1)\n";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ... Tail>
class Foo<T, Tail...> : public Foo<Tail...>  {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo (2)\n" ;
    }
};


class Bar : public Foo<std::string, int> {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    void test(Foo<Args...> f) {
        f.foo();
    }
};

class Baz : public Foo<int, std::string> {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    void test(Foo<Args...> f) {
        f.foo();
    }
};


int main() {
    Bar a;
    Bar b;
    a.test(static_cast<Foo<std::string, int>>(b));

    Bar c;
    Baz d;
    c.test(static_cast<Foo<int, std::string>>(d));   
    
    return 0;
}
```

You'll find the code here: https://godbolt.org/z/YjPqaKdbj